# ¿Cómo verifico que una variable entera se movió N elementos?

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una 'SeekBar' que envía su valor (de 0 a 255) por bluetooth a un Arduino.

En la función 'onProgressChanged' propia de la SeekBar hago que envíe el valor por bluetooth. El detalle es que si la barra se mueve muy rápido, el Arduino empalma los valores y forma números enormes.

La solución que se me ocurrió fue que solo cada 10 cambios (ascendentes y descendentes) en "progress" envíe el valor:
0,10,20,...,255.

De ese modo es imposible que se empalmen en el Arduino.
También se me ocurre una manera en el Arduino para evitar este error, pero me gustaría saber cómo programo la solución de los 10 cambios.

Estoy haciendo mi app en Kotlin, pero se agradecen respuestas en Kotlin y en Java.

Comment: Hola, Agrega el código por favor,  esto es una tarea de la escuela?, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la respuesta, me estaba complicando la vida. La primera solución que econtré fue hacer una lista de múltiplos de 10 (de 0 a 260) y verificar que progress estuviera en esa lista:

```
val lista = listOf(0,10,20,30,40)
...
if (proress in lista){
   //do something
}
```

Funcionó! Pero es una solución algo compleja para lo que en realidad necesitaba. Finalmente recordé que uno de los primeros programas que haces cuando aprendes a programar (luego del hola mundo) es uno que te devuelva el residuo al hacer una división, y eso fue lo que ocupé:

```
if (progress % 10 == 0{
   //do something
}
```